# BASH - transfer large files and process after transfer limiting the number of processes

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, background

I have several large files that I need to transfer to a local machine and process.  The transfer takes about as long as the processing of the file, and I would like to start processing it immediately after it transfers.  But the processing could take longer than the transfer, and I don't want the processes to keep building up, but I would like to limit it to some number, say 4.

Consider the following:

```
LIST_OF_LARGE_FILES="file1 file2 file3 file4 ... fileN"
for FILE in $LIST_OF_LARGE_FILES; do
    scp user@host:$FILE ./
    myCommand $FILE &
done
```

This will transfer each file and start processing it after the transfer while allowing the next file to start transferring.  However, if `myCommand $FILE` takes much longer than the time to transfer one file, these could keep piling up and bogging down the local machine.  So I would like to limit `myCommand` to maybe 2-4 parallel instances.  Subsequent attempts to invoke `myCommand` should buffer it until a "slot" is open.  Is there a good way to do this in BASH (using `xargs` or other utilities is acceptable).

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the help in getting this far.  Now I'm trying to implement the following logic:

```
LIST_OF_LARGE_FILES="file1 file2 file3 file4 ... fileN"
for FILE in $LIST_OF_LARGE_FILES; do
    echo "Starting on $FILE"  # should go to terminal output
    scp user@host:$FILE ./
    echo "Processing $FILE"   # should go to terminal output
    echo $FILE                # should go through pipe to parallel
done | parallel myCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **GNU Parallel** for that. Just echo the commands you want run into `parallel` and it will run one job per CPU core your machine has.

```
for f in ... ; do
   scp ...
   echo ./process "$f"
done | parallel
```

If you specifically want 4 processes at a time, use `parallel -j 4`.

If you want a progress bar, use `parallel --bar`.

Alternatively, echo just the filename with null-termination, and add the processing command into the invocation of `parallel`:

```
for f in ... ; do
   scp ...
   printf "%s\0" "$f"
done | parallel -0 -j4 ./process
```

Comment: Thanks Mark!  I think that construct is just what I was after.  The only thing extra is if I could also echo some statements in the for loop that would get sent to the terminal output and not to parallel.  See updated post.

Comment: Try `echo XYZ > /dev/tty` maybe?

Comment: If the script is not always run in a terminal (e.g. cron). Then use `echo XYZ >&2` instead.